# instagram api submission website url

Tags: android, api, instagram, instagram-api

**Overview**

I created an android app that uses the instagram api. I do not have a website for it yet.

When i put the 2 requirements >> Website URL:http://www.google.com and Privacy Policy URL:http://www.google.com, i manage to create a client successfully but it was in sandbox mode. Now i sent it in for submission to make the client live but it shows the error below

General issues:
We are unable to access your website. Please make sure to provide a valid URL and any login credentials required to view your site.

Do i have to create my own website for it to become live?

Comment: please provide some lines of code so we would understand your issue

Comment: I have same problem. Did you solve it?